# python dropbox api error

Tags: python, api, dropbox

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#python)

So far so good but the upload example give me errors. The code:

```
from dropbox import client, rest, session

f = open('txt2.txt') # upload a file
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
print "uploaded:", response
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox_ul.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'put_file'
```

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: The new code I'm trying. This is actually from the dropbox developer website. As I stated earlier, I did go through the authentication and setup:

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
APP_KEY = 'iqxjea6s7ctxv9j'
APP_SECRET = 'npac0nca3p3ct9f'

# ACCESS_TYPE should be 'dropbox' or 'app_folder' as configured for your app
ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'

sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE )

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

# Make the user sign in and authorize this token
url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)
print "url:", url
print "Please authorize in the browser. After you're done, press enter."
raw_input()

# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)

client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
print "linked account:", client.account_info()

f = open('txt2.txt')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
print "uploaded:", response

folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
print "metadata:", folder_metadata

f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/magnum-opus.txt',rev='362e2029684fe')
out = open('magnum-opus.txt', 'w')
out.write(f)
print(metadata)
```

and the error:

```
   url: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=jqbasca63c0a84m
    Please authorize in the browser. After you're done, press enter.

    linked account: {'referral_link': 'https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTMxMzM4NjY5', 'display_name': 'Greg Lorincz', 'uid': 3133866, 'country': 'GB', 'quota_info': {'shared': 78211, 'quota': 28185722880, 'normal': 468671581}, 'email': 'alkopop79@gmail.com'}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "dropb.py", line 28, in <module>
        response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-1.4-py2.7.egg/dropbox/client.py", line 149, in put_file
        return RESTClient.PUT(url, file_obj, headers)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-1.4-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 146, in PUT
        return cls.request("PUT", url, body=body, headers=headers, raw_response=raw_response)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-1.4-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 113, in request
        raise ErrorResponse(r)
    dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [403] 'The provided token does not allow this operation'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized the client object. Refer to the tutorial again and you'll see this:

```
client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
```

The sess object must also be initialized before calling the client module's DropboxClient method:

```
sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
```

You should have all the required parameters (i.e., APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE) assigned to you when you register your application.

Comment: Tried to add the lines with all the authentication keys and it gave me an authentication error.

Comment: On the tutorial page, look under the section marked "In Conclusion". You'll see where they recommend setting APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, and ACCESS_TYPE. These values are usually hexadecimal string values that might look like (but not exactly) this "fd23433abc33fg3g33g90". These are provided to you when you sign up as a developer. If you don't set these properly, then you'll get an authentication error.

Comment: You can sign in to see the app keys for your project here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#python

Comment: Ah, make sense. I did sign up and an other example works just fine. I wonder, is there a way to avoid having to allow access (copy link, open it in browser, click 'Allow', hit enter in terminal...)?

Comment: As I said, the signing up is done. I have the API keys, the terminal prompts me to open the URL in the browser, then click on Allow... all done. Yet the example is not working.

Comment: You choose your access type when you create your app. Try setting it to "Full Dropbox"... create a new app if you can't modify the existing one.

Comment: Tried that, I mean changing the acces mode from app_folder to dropbox. Did not make any difference.

Comment: No, there are privileges you set when you first register your app. This forum

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=29119

may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Created a new app, this time changed the acces type to "full dropbox". It all seems fine however it still cannot find the txt file. I wonder where the heck should I put it? it's in the same folder as the script!

Comment: It seems to work finally with this message: dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [404] 'File not found'   I wonder how can I avoid having to do the whole authentication process, such as having to open the URL then click the 'Allow' button... can I just store the auth details somewhere?

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help. I don't want to stray beyond the scope of your original question, but I think what you need is found in Python's httplib module: http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html. That's one of several ways you can make the HTTP request you want without doing the whole browser cut-paste thing.

Comment: i also get the "Authentication failed" and "request token was not found" errors. how did you solve it. my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214242/use-python-dropbox-api-with-django?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I followed the edited code of yours and things worked out perfectly.

```
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'enter-your-app_key'
app_secret = 'enter-your-app_secret'

ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'

sess = session.DropboxSession(app_key, app_secret, ACCESS_TYPE )

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

# Make the user sign in and authorize this token
url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)
print "url:", url
print "Please authorize in the browser. After you're done, press enter."
raw_input()

# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)

client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
print "linked account:", client.account_info()

f = open('/home/anurag/Documents/sayan.odt')
response = client.put_file('/sayan.odt', f)
print "uploaded:", response
```

Notice the response and file location on your system, in your code that doesn't matches.

Thanks.